How to prevent JFileChooser from cancelling, when user types a filename in DIRECTORIES_ONLY mode
When you show an instance of JFileChooser set to DIRECTORIES_ONLY mode, it still allows manually typing filenames in the textfield. It is possible to override the approveSelection() method to further validate any selection made by the user, however this method isn't even called when a valid file is selected in this mode, because JFileChooser just cancels when you click the Approve button.
How can I change this behaviour? I want to show a warning message when the user selects a file instead of a directory, and keep the dialog open so they have to try again. Similar to how you can override approveSelection() to show a confirmation dialog when clicking the Approve button before closing the dialog, when saving a file that already exists.
(I don't understand why the default behaviour of JFileChooser in directories-only mode allows file selections to go through anyway)
I have already looked into the FileChooserUI class to check the internal behaviour of what actually calls approveSelection() and cancelSelection(), but it looks far too complicated to override for a simple goal such as this.

One option is to check the result of the JFileChooser.  If it's a file, display a warning message and redisplay the JFileChooser in your code.  A bit clunkier, but workable.

That would cause a recursion, which I find unsafe and want to avoid. The method that builds and shows the file chooser, is also what's checking its result. It would have to call itself to reopen the dialog, which means it cannot "save" any previous browsing done in the first show

Actually, I've tried that and it's not possible. In this case where JFileChooser cancels the dialog, it has a null selected file. So I cannot differentiate a normal cancel operation (or even error) from this special case.

To make JFileChooser return an APPROVE_OPTION state and a file that is selected instead of CANCEL_OPTION and null the FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES selection mode and a custom FileFilter (matching nothing) can be used.
To show a chooser repeatedly (as already suggested in the comments) a dialog opening can be placed inside a loop (not recursion) which will continue only if user keeps selecting a file that is not valid. It depends on a use case but an additional check can be made to ensure that selected directory exists.
Once a loop ends the chooser return state will be kept in a variable allowing to differentiate between approve, cancel, and error operations.
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Directories", "NON_EXISTENT_EXTENSION"));
fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

int fcReturnState;
while (true) {
    fcReturnState = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    boolean valid = (file != null && file.exists() && file.isDirectory());

    if (fcReturnState == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION && !valid) {
        
        String fileErr = (file == null) ? "No file selected." : String.format(
                    "%s \"%s\" %s.", (file.exists() ? "File" : "Directory"),
                    file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    (!file.exists() ? "does not exist" : "is not a directory"));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fileErr + " Please try again.",
                "Warning", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
if (fcReturnState == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Directory selected: " + fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

} else if (fcReturnState == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Selection cancelled");

} else if (fcReturnState == JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Selection error occurred");
}


There are actually many NPEs in the String.format() call, since file can be null if not valid. But I like the loop approach, since it avoids recursion and re-creating the fc.

Good catch, thanks! The code has been updated to handle that.

I accomplished fixing the problem I think is happening, by overriding the cancelSelection() method, and peeking into the UI implementation, recreating the file from the textfield and then manually testing if it is an existing file.
Because this is the method that (wrongfully in my opinion) gets called by the UI's ApproveSelectionAction, and the actual file reported by the FileChooser has been nullified at this point.
@Override
public void cancelSelection()
{
    final BasicFileChooserUI myui = (BasicFileChooserUI) this.getUI();
    final File file = this.getFileSystemView().createFileObject(myui.getFileName());
    if (file != null && file.isFile())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot select \"" + file.getName() + "\", as it isn't a directory.", "Not a directory", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return; // canceling cancellation
    }
    super.cancelSelection();
}


But this is a "late" fix, as a latch ditch effort. There may be a better approach
